# Text not showing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have two functions in a class called "NPC", which will be used to display a textbox to display text the NPC is meant to be saying. Here is the whole NPC class for context:

```
class NPC(object):
        def __init__(self, path, x, y):
                self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
                self.x = x
                self.y = y


        def spawn(self, surface):
                surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

        def text_objects(self, text, font):
                textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
                return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

        def interact(self, text):
                textSize = pygame.font.Font("cour.ttf",28) #specify text size
                TextRect.center = (width/2, height/1.5) #where text will be
                TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText) #allow text to be positioned
                gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect) #display text

                pygame.display.update() #updates screen
```

the function is called later on here:

```
person1 = NPC("talkToThis.png",100, 200)
pygame.display.flip() #paints screen
gameRun = True #allow game events to loop/be carried out more than once

while gameRun: #while game is running:

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
                        pygame.quit() #quit game
                        gameRun = False #break the loop.
                        quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if key[pygame.K_RETURN]:
                                person1.interact("hi")
```

When I run the code, no error appears, but when I press enter the message doesn't show up. At first I suspected it was because the font wasn't in the same file as the code, however after copy/pasting it still didn't work. I have a feeling that the error lies somewhere in the two functions to do with the text, possibly as a missed piece of information. It could also due to "person1" already containing three parameters which are needed for the "spawn" function and for the **init**.

full code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
(width, height) = (600, 400) #specify window resolution
bg_colour = (100,20,156) #specify bg colour

player_path = "downChara.png" #specifies image path

moveDown = True
moveUp = True
moveRight = True
moveLeft = True

class Player(object): #representitive of the player's overworld sprite
        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha() #creates image, the player_path variable allowing it to be updated
            self.X = (width/2) -16; # x co-ord of player
            self.Y = (height/2)-16; # y co-ord of player


        def handle_keys(self, down, up, left, right): #handling the keys/inputs
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            dist = 5 #distance travelled in one frame of the program
            if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and down == True: #if down
                self.Y += dist #move down the length of dist
                player_path = "downChara.png" #change image to down
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_UP] and up == True: #if up
                self.Y -= dist #move up the length of dist
                player_path = "upChara.png" #change to up
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and right == True: #etc.
                self.X += dist
                player_path = "rightChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()
            elif key[pygame.K_LEFT] and left == True:
                self.X -= dist
                player_path = "leftChara.png"
                self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path).convert_alpha()

        def outX(coord): #"coord" acts the same as "self"
                return (coord.X)
        def outY(coord):
                return (coord.Y)


        def draw(self, surface): #draw to the surface/screen
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.X, self.Y))


class NPC(object):
        def __init__(self, path, x, y):
                self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
                self.x = x
                self.y = y


        def spawn(self, surface):
                surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

        def text_objects(self, text, font):
                textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
                return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

        def interact(self, text):
                textSize = pygame.font.Font("cour.ttf",28) #specify text size
                TextRect.center = (width/2, height/1.5) #where text will be
                TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText) #allow text to be positioned
                gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect) #display text

                pygame.display.update() #updates screen



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) #create window
pygame.display.set_caption('EduGame') #specify window name

player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

person1 = NPC("talkToThis.png",100, 200)


boarderX = player.outX()
boarderY = player.outY()
print (boarderX, boarderY) #making sure they both returned properly

pygame.display.flip() #paints screen
gameRun = True #allow game events to loop/be carried out more than once

while gameRun: #while game is running:


        for event in pygame.event.get(): #all the events (movement, etc) to be here.
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
                        pygame.quit() #quit game
                        gameRun = False #break the loop.
                        quit()
                event = pygame.event.poll()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                        person1.interact("hi")

        player.handle_keys(moveDown, moveUp, moveLeft, moveRight) #handle keys

        screen.fill(bg_colour) #draw background colour

        player.draw(screen) #draws player

        person1.spawn(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

        posX = player.outX()
        posY = player.outY()

        if posX > width - 32: #this is because the sprite's "X" is determined in the top left corner, meaning we have to subtract the width from the measurement
                moveRight = False
        else:
                moveRight = True
        if posX < 0:
                moveLeft = False
        else:
                moveLeft = True
        if posY > height - 32: #this is because the sprite's "X" is determined in the top left corner, meaning we have to subtract the width from the measurement
                moveDown = False
        else:
                moveDown = True
        if posY < 0:
                moveUp = False
        else:
                moveUp = True



        clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: Post the full code, pls

Comment: @SamperMan I'll add the full code to the question now.

Comment: OK, waiting for it.

Comment: @Polybrow check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need your for loop when checking pygame events.
Then, choose only one from the ways to catch your key events:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RETURN]:
```

or

```
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
```

The full piece of code:

```
while gameRun: #while game is running:

    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #if the "x" is pressed
        pygame.quit() #quit game
        gameRun = False #break the loop.
        quit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
        person1.interact("hi")
    ....
```

Comment: thanks, that's helped solve the input/button pressing issue. it's also helped in finding another error that was in the actual text function itself, so I'll get to work on that